# Ionic 4: modal not showing

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, angular6, ionic4

I'm trying to use the modal components from Ionic 4 in an Angular 6 application that has even Bootstrap installed, but I'm having some troubles. I'm sure that the modal is created, since I logged the html created by the instruction:

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
   component: ModalPage
});
console.log(modal);
return modal.present();
```

It returns something like

```
<ion-modal class="sc-ion-modal-ios-h sc-ion-modal-ios-s modal modal-ios hydrated show-modal" id="ion-overlay-1" no-router="" aria-modal="true" style="z-index: 20001;"><ion-backdrop class="sc-ion-modal-ios hydrated" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 0.4;"></ion-backdrop><div role="dialog" class="modal-wrapper modal-wrapper-ios sc-ion-modal-ios" style="transform: translateY(0%); opacity: 1;"><app-manutenzioni-storico _nghost-c1="" class="ion-page"><ion-header _ngcontent-c1="" class="header header-ios hydrated"><ion-toolbar _ngcontent-c1="" class="hydrated"><ion-title _ngcontent-c1="" class="title-ios hydrated">manutenzioni-storico</ion-title></ion-toolbar></ion-header><ion-content _ngcontent-c1="" padding="" class="overscroll hydrated" style="--offset-top:0px; --offset-bottom:0px;"><ion-button _ngcontent-c1="" expand="block" routerlink="/manutenzioni-nuova" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-expand="block" ng-reflect-router-link="/manutenzioni-nuova" class="button button-block button-solid ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated">Nuova Manutenzione</ion-button><ion-list _ngcontent-c1="" class="list list-ios hydrated"><ion-item _ngcontent-c1="" class="in-list item ion-focusable hydrated item-label"><ion-label _ngcontent-c1="" class="sc-ion-label-ios-h sc-ion-label-ios-s hydrated">Pokémon Yellow</ion-label></ion-item><ion-item _ngcontent-c1="" class="in-list item ion-focusable hydrated item-label"><ion-label _ngcontent-c1="" class="sc-ion-label-ios-h sc-ion-label-ios-s hydrated">Mega Man X</ion-label></ion-item><ion-item _ngcontent-c1="" class="in-list item ion-focusable hydrated item-label"><ion-label _ngcontent-c1="" class="sc-ion-label-ios-h sc-ion-label-ios-s hydrated">The Legend of Zelda</ion-label></ion-item><ion-item _ngcontent-c1="" class="in-list item ion-focusable hydrated item-label"><ion-label _ngcontent-c1="" class="sc-ion-label-ios-h sc-ion-label-ios-s hydrated">Pac-Man</ion-label></ion-item><ion-item _ngcontent-c1="" class="in-list item ion-focusable hydrated item-label"><ion-label _ngcontent-c1="" class="sc-ion-label-ios-h sc-ion-label-ios-s hydrated">Super Mario World</ion-label></ion-item></ion-list></ion-content></app-manutenzioni-storico></div></ion-modal>
```

Here my code:

list.page.html

```
<ion-button color="warning" (click)="presentModal()">Open modal</ion-button>
```

list.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ListPage } from './list.page';
import {ModalPage} from '../modal/modal.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListPage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ListPage, ModalPage],
  entryComponents:
  [
    ModalPage
  ]
})
export class ListPageModule {}
```

list.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ModalPage} from '../modal/modal.page';
import {ModalController} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.page.scss']
})
export class ListPage implements OnInit {

constructor(public modalController: ModalController) {  }
async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage
    });
    console.log(modal);
    return modal.present();
  }
}
```

The modal doesn't show. I've tried several times and tutorials, but I didn't succeed in. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you imported ManutenzioniStoricoPageModule / ModalPageModule in app.module.ts imports?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but the result is: Type ModalPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ModalPageModule and ListPageModule! Please consider moving ModalPage to a higher module that imports ModalPageModule and ListPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ModalPage then import that NgModule in ModalPageModule and ListPageModule.

Comment: The answer is exactly that -- just import `ModalPage` once in just one module. Don't import it in both `ModalPageModule` and `ListPageModule`. You only need the `ModalPage` component right? You can just delete `ModalPageModule` if you're not using it in any route (and I don't think you should that). Did you create the modal via `ionic g page modal`? It would have been better to just create it via `ionic g component modal`

Comment: Remove the ModalPage in declarations and entryComponent in `list.module.ts`. To access the ModalPage, the import of `ModalPageModule` in `app.module.ts` is suffient.